# Computational complexity of Inverse FFT

Tags: math, big-o, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to obtain the computational complexity for the inverse of the fast Fourier transform (IFFT). I already know it’s *O*(*n*log*n*) for a one-dimensional vector of *n* positions, but in my case, firstly I have a product of two FFTs. Then, I want to calculate its corresponding IFFT, and obtain its computational complexity.

*X*(*w*) and *Q*(*w*) are both one-dimensional vectors, and both have *n* positions.

Simply, if *X*(*w*) and *Q*(*w*) are FFTs, considering their product is still an FFT (according to the convolution property), what would be the computational complexity of the corresponding IFFT?

Comment: Should be on programmers stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still O(N log N).  The ifft doesn't care how you get the data, and the element-wise multiplication is O(N).

Comment: thanks mate. I was thinking same, but I had doubt lol. anywat im not into programming so much. @evan